# Expectation of Brownian Motions

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $$I_{N}^{\alpha}(t)=\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}W(t_{j}^{\alpha})[W(t_{j+1})-W(t_{j})] \ \ \ (*)$$

$$\textrm{where} \ t_{j}=\frac{jt}{N} \ \textrm{and} \ t_{j}^{\alpha}=\alpha t_{j}+(1-\alpha )t_{j+1} \ \ $$

I need to calculate the $\lim_{N\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(I_{N}^{\alpha}(t))$. I've expanded out (*) and found that the first 2 terms go to 0 but I'm struggling to find the final term. Please help.

Comment: You have to use $\mathbb{E}(W_s W_t) = \min\{s,t\}$... that's it.

Comment: @saz , I'm not sure how that relates to this problem as the sum expands to $$I_{N}^{\alpha}(t)=\sum_{j}[W(t_{j+1})-W(t_{j}^{\alpha})][W(t_{j}^{\alpha})-W(t_{j})] + \sum_{j}[W(t_{j}^{\alpha})-W(t_{j})]^{2} + \sum_{j}W(t_{j})[W(t_{j+1})-W(t_{j})]$$. ?

Comment: There is nothing to expand if you want to calculate the expectation value of the sum. Is there a square missing (i.e. do you want to calculate $\mathbb{E}((I_N^{\alpha})^2)$ and not $\mathbb{E}(I_N^{\alpha})$)...?

Comment: Ah okay, I understand that now. The second part of the problem is the squared version. Is the way to go about that from first principles how I've started above then?

Comment: So, computing $E(I_N^\alpha(t))$ is not a problem anymore, or what?

Comment: Yes, I have calculated that the expectation is $(1- \alpha)T$. Now I need to show from first principles that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(I_{N}^{\alpha}(t)^{2} = (1- \alpha)^2 t^{2} +\frac{t^{2}}{2}$. Do you know how to go about solving this, @Did ?

Comment: Yes, but before that, we would like to see what you tried to compute the second moment.

Comment: So far I have taken the expanded sum as shown in my first comment and I have squared it and produced a large number of sums, 16 I think. Then I am now attempting to break the sums into parts and show how they converge. I'm guessing many are going to converge to zero. Is this the way I should be attempting to go about it @Did?